How to read a Nested JSON in Pyspark
I am trying to read a nested JSON downloaded from: text
When running the code:
# Read the JSON file with specified options
df = spark.read.format("json") \
    .option("inferschema", "true") \
    .option("mode", "permissive") \
    .load("/FileStore/tables/nested-2.json")

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()


I am getting the error :

AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV
files are disallowed when the referenced columns only include the
internal corrupt record column.

While this is happening for file5.JSON, this did not happen for file4.JSON on the link provided. Can anyone point out the issue.

Did the error happen on the load() call?  On the show() call?  Don't make us guess.  Please post the full error traceback message.

You have to use spark.read.option("multiline","true"). The code should look like this:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Read Nested JSON with Schema") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read the JSON file with specified options
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").format("json") \
    .option("inferschema", "true") \
    .option("mode", "permissive") \
    .load("file5.json")

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()

